# Is it possible to keep reusing shop bough probiotics?

Tags: digestion, probiotics, gut-microbiota-flora, indigestion

I only buy it once, and use it again and again for years when I make sauerkraut or any kind of fermented food

Is it possible and beneficial?

Comment: If you are using it "for years" you answered this yourself: "is it possible?" – But welcome to HealthSE, john-thomas! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). Given my initial remark, please edit your question with the help of [how to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your question. Could you please rephrase your question with a topic that is a bit more clearly stated? Thank you!

Comment: by reusing i meant eg.: making yoghurt from raw milk with a probiotic, then using that yoghurt to make a second,third...batch again and again, can it be just as beneficial as drinking the raw probiotic?

Comment: what is shop bough?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Natures-Way-Primadophilus-Vegetarian-Capsules/dp/B005S6Y8OU

like this one?

Comment: is it possible to  "lower the price" this way?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, you don't want to keep probiotics for a long time - they are living bacteria and will die fairly quickly compared to most things. For instance, if you waited a year (just a guess based on years of experience, no formal source) the potency of the probiotic will be much less because many of the bacteria will have died. If you buy it, you should use it on a regular basis until it's gone - including using it in sauerkrat!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! We *require* a 'formal' [reliable reference](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/783/11231) for answers. Aside from that, your statement looks like making sense for pills, not sauerkraut (and similar applications). That means especially potency and food-stuff application *needs* backup to prove your point. [Have you ever read about family recipes for kimchi?]